# How to keep background color when typing in a cell?

Tags: vba, excel-2010

I do not like Excel 2010's white worksheet background so I set it to a charcoal color using a 25x25 pixel *.jpg by selecting `Page Layout-> Background` and selecting the *.jpg.

I then set the worksheet font to yellow for maximum contrast. Looks good!

But then a problem occurs. When I select a cell and start typing. When I start typing, the background color of the cell turns white. With yellow font I can't see the text with white background (no contrast).

**How can I type in the cell and it be a dark background color?** It doesn't have to be the exact *.jpg background color - it could be anything dark so that I can see the yellow text.

I am assuming that a VBA macro will do the trick. I could not find an event for `OnTypingInCell` that I could set the Interior color. The closest I could find is `Workbook_SheetSelectionChange` but it seems to be called immediately before typing in the cell.

Comment: Macros do not run when you're in "edit mode"

Comment: Why not click on the cell, then click in the Formula Bar, and then type in the Formula Bar.

Comment: So what is wrong with using the `SelectionChange` event and setting the `Target.Interior.Color`. This will set the background as soon as you enter the cell which seems to be what you want is it not?

Comment: @Tim: what is "edit mode"? Do you mean when I type in the cell?

Comment: @Gary'sStudent: Because that is a workaround. I want a solution.

Comment: @engineersmnky: that is precisely what I tried. Everything is just fine with that approach until the moment you start typing. That is to say I can select a cell which triggers the Workbook_SheetSelectionChange event, which then sets the Interior color, but then the moment I start typing in the cell the background turns white and the font remains yellow. This is happening *after* the Workbook_SheetSelectionChange event and therefore that particular event is of no use in correcting the problem. That is why I am asking for something like a OnTypingInCell event - but that doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: Yes - when you're typing in the cell.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like it would work for your question (uses DarkGray and Yellow)

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Target.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = -0.499984740745262
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Target.Font
        .Color = -16711681
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try this solution yourself? I tried, and it did not resolve the issue. Please try it for yourself and let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: Yes it works for me but I have Excel 2007 so it is possible this functionality changed in 2010

Answer (score 0):

*****SOLUTION*****

0) Setup a background color [click here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/20315-default-worksheet-background-color.html)

1) open VBA editor (Alt-F11)

2) right click ThisWorkbook and View Code

3) In code window select Workbook from dropdown

4) In code window select SheetSelectionChange from dropdown

5) Add the following code to the code window:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Static OldRange As Range

    If Cells(1, 1).Interior.ColorIndex <> xlColorIndexNone Then
        Cells(1, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
        Cells(1, 1).Font.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
        Cells(1, 1).Borders.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
    End If

    Selection(1, 1).Activate
    On Error Resume Next
    OldRange.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
    OldRange.Font.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
    OldRange.Borders.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
    Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 48 ' background color
    Target.Font.ColorIndex = 6 ' font color
    Target.Borders.ColorIndex = 9 ' border color
    Set OldRange = Target
End Sub
```

*****BONUS*****

Q: How do I setup an Excel template?

A: Good question! If you want to open Excel and see your new background (everytime!) perform the following steps:

0) Create two folders:

```
    C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART\
    C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART\background\
```

1) Open Excel and save the following three files:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART\Book.xltm
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART\Sheet.xltm
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART\background\<filename of background color>
```

2) open Book.xltm and configure the background using `<filename of background color>`

3) configure any other items in `Book.xltm` that you want when Excel opens.

4) copy paste `Book.xltm` to `Sheet.xltm` and delete extra sheets in `Sheet.xltm` (only one sheet)

5) save and close excel

6) open excel -> your changes are now in place

Note: `Sheet.xltm` is what is used when you click the 'new sheet' button in Excel

Comment: I chose to use *.xltm because I enjoy macros. You might want to try the non-macro template file.

Comment: Update: this solution is terrible. Not because of the macro. But because Excel developers in their infinite wisdom (sarcasm is necessary) decided that running a macro will clear the undo and redo stack. Thanks Microsoft. Please fix this. Note to others: until Microsoft fixes this you should ignore my solution. Unless you want to implement your own reno and undo stacks using VBA!